# Django / Sending email with Mail Service Prodiver like Mailjet

Tags: django, mailjet

I have installed django-anymail

My SPF and DKIM are configured in my ISP

Here is my settings.py :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "anymail.backends.mailjet.EmailBackend"
ANYMAIL = {
    "MAILJET_API_KEY": os.getenv('MYAPP_MAILJET_API_KEY'),
    "MAILJET_SECRET_KEY": os.getenv('MYAPP_MAILJET_API_SECRET'),
}
EMAIL_HOST = 'in-v3.mailjet.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '????'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '????'
EMAIL_HOST_PORT = 587
```

Views.py

```
send_mail('contact form','click',mail1,[mail2],fail_silently=False)
```

I got confused for
**EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD**

As I want to use mailjet, is it necessary ? Also is send_mail the right function in this case ?

Comment: There is a package available for [Mailjet](https://pypi.org/project/django-mailjet/) try following that approch

Comment: Thanks. Work better for me than django-anymail

Comment: Can you share the connection settings in settings.py. i used the same thing mentioned in the package. But it ask for email_host_password